# User profile synchronization for User profile properties

Tags: 2010, user-profile, profile-sync

IN SP2010, I have added 3 new User profile properties by Central Admin of type boolean, datetime and string.Then I added data for the user in the profile for these new properties. I ran the "User Profile Service Application Proxy - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization" job so that these new properties appear in SiteUserInfoList (hidden list) so that I can query this list by CAML from code.

What I noticed was that the first two properties i.e. boolean and datetime properties appeared in the Fields of the list, but the string property is not appearing. I tried to synchronize many times, but could not get this proeprty to appear in this list.

The user profile application is not configured for syncing from AD yet.

Any tips on how to check the logs for this issue ?

I tried the following: 1. IIS reset 2. Event viewer (no error was logged).

Already posted in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852793/user-profile-synchronization-for-user-profile-properties-in-sharepoint-2010)

Comment: In the property edit page 
Number of profiles using this property: (is this value set to 0)


Are these options checked or unchecked in the property edit page in CA 

--
Show in the profile properties section of the user's profile page 
Show on the Edit Details page

Comment: the no. of profiles using this property is not 0. The options 'Show in the profile properties section of the user's profile page' and 'Show on the Edit Details page' are checked.

Answer (score 5):

Have you enabled "replicable" on the field properties?

If this isnt enabled, the properties are not propagated to the hidden user list

Edit:
if you look at [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4965/how-to-configure-replicable-properties-in-user-profile), it seems that not all user profile types are propagated.
Change one of the properties to TEXT just to test if this is the cause of this.

Comment: Yes, the replicable checkbox is checked for all of these properties.

Comment: I tried creating a text field and then syncing, but it still did not show any value. If there is a restriction of TEXT field it does not serve my purpose, so instead I am programmatically doing people search now and is working fine with that.

Comment: Good choice, that is also IMO often a better alternative. Another option would be to access the user profile properties programmatically