# User profile synchronization for User profile properties in SharePoint 2010

Tags: user-profile, profile-sync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User profile synchronization for User profile properties](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37728/user-profile-synchronization-for-user-profile-properties)

IN SP2010, I have added 3 new User profile properties by Central Admin of type boolean, datetime and string.Then I added data for the user in the profile for these new properties. 
I ran the "User Profile Service Application Proxy - User Profile to SharePoint Full Synchronization" job so that these new properties appear in SiteUserInfoList (hidden list) so that I can query this list by CAML from code.

What I noticed was that the first two properties i.e. boolean and datetime properties appeared in the Fields of the list, but the string property is not appearing. I tried to synchronize many times, but could not get this proeprty to appear in this list.

The user profile application is not configured for syncing from AD yet.

Any tips on how to check the logs for this issue ?

I tried the following:
1. IIS reset 
2. Event viewer (no error was logged)

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled "replicable" on the field properties?

If this isnt enabled, the properties are not propagated to the hidden user list